# Jquery animate not working in IE?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using jquery to animate a background position of an image, it works in modern browsers but not in IE. Any help is much appreciated, thanks :)

```
$("#btn-home").click(function(){
  $('#line').animate({backgroundPosition: '0px 0', duration:2000});
  })
  $("#btn-intro").click(function(){
  $('#line').animate({backgroundPosition: '116px 0', duration:2000});
  })
  $("#btn-prizes").click(function(){
        $('#line').animate({backgroundPosition: '231px 0', duration:2000});
      })
    $("#btn-part").click(function(){
        $('#line').animate({backgroundPosition: '345px 0', duration:2000});
      })
    $("#btn-prog").click(function(){
        $('#line').animate({backgroundPosition: '460px 0', duration:2000});
      })
    $("#btn-judge").click(function(){
        $('#line').animate({backgroundPosition: '575px 0', duration:2000});
      })
    $("#btn-past").click(function(){
        $('#line').animate({backgroundPosition: '690px 0', duration:2000});
      })
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a fiddle? What does this code do in IE?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$('#line').animate({backgroundPosition: '345px 0'}, 2000);
```

Comment: @ps2 - Did you get a chance to look at it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn-home").click(function(){
  $('#line').animate({backgroundPosition: '0px 0', duration:2000});
  })
```

Is Wrong.

I don't think there is anything such as `duration: {NUMBER}` in Animate.

Try:

```
$("#btn-home").click(function(){
  $('#line').animate({backgroundPosition: '0px 0', 2000});
  })
```